# formtastic errors with remote true

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.2, formtastic

When i use :remote => true formtastic does not autoclear the form after successful submission

also if i use a remote form for updating the data as shown in the following code , the form is always stuck associated with that model , not allowing me to save a new model , even though i attempt to create a new model using build and try passing ti through locals in the js

So heres the formtastic view

```
<%= semantic_form_for @deliverable,:remote=>true do |f| %>
<%= f.input :quantity, :as => :number , :name => "items"%>
<%= f.input :product_id, :as => :select, :collection => current_user.products.all %>
<%= f.actions%>
<% end %>
```

and here's the controller

```
def create
@micropost = current_user.microposts.find(Rails.cache.read('mp_id'))
@deliverable = @micropost.deliverables.build(params[:deliverable])
@curr_product = current_user.products.find(params[:deliverable][:product_id])
@deliverable.del_price_cents = @deliverable.quantity * @curr_product.price_cents
if @deliverable.save
   @del_items = @micropost.deliverables.find(:all)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to root_path}
    format.js
 end   
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to root_path}
    format.js    {render :text => @deliverable.errors.full_messages.to_s}
 end   




end
end
def edit
 @deliverable = Deliverable.find(params[:id])
 respond_to do |format|

   format.js 
 end

 end
 def update
 @deliholder = Deliverable.find(params[:id])
 if @deliholder.update_attributes(params[:deliverable])
 @micropost = current_user.microposts.find(Rails.cache.read('mp_id'))

 @del_items = @micropost.deliverables.find(:all) 
 @deliverable = @micropost.deliverables.new


  respond_to do |format|
    format.js 
  end
  else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to root_path}
    format.js    {render :text => @deliverable.errors.full_messages.to_s}
  end 
 end  
end
```

and heres the js view for edit

```
$("#deliver-list").hide();
$("#deliver-holder").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(    'shared/deliverable_formtastic',:locals => {:deliverable => @deliverable }))%>");
```

and the js for update

```
alert("the deliverable has been updated ")
$("#deliver-list").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(  'shared/deliverable_list' ,:locals => {:del_items => @del_items } ))%>");
$("#deliver-list").show();
$("#deliver-holder").empty();
$("#deliver-holder").html("<%= escape_javascript( render( 'shared/deliverable_formtastic',:locals => {:deliverable => @deliverable }))%>");
```

i tried replacing the @deliverable with @deliholder for updating , as shown above , makes no difference , passing or not passing @deliverables in the js locals also makes no difference

create.js

```
alert("the deliverable has been saved to the  bill ");
$('#fc')[0].reset();
$("#deliver-list").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(  'shared/deliverable_list' ,:locals => {:del_items => @del_items } ))%>");
```

Comment: What's the js template for #create?

Comment: do you reset the form with $("FORM_ID_OR_CLASS")[0].reset(); in your js.erb file? in my case I have $(".new_comment")[0].reset(); to create/update a comment

Comment: Thanks rmagnum2002 your form reset works perfectly , in my create.js , so now the form clears after every saving . But it doesnt work even when i include it in the update.js